# How do I pass ALT-TAB through Teamviewer app to remote computer?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I run TeamViewer on Ubuntu to access  a remote Windows machine. I selected Actions > Send Key Combinations, and set the window to full screen, but whenever I press ALT-TAB, it always gets intercepted by Ubuntu and  switches local apps, not remote apps. How do I use ALT-TAB on the remote Windows desktop?

Ubuntu 16.04, TeamViewer 11.0.67687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/ccsm) to temporally turn off Alt-Tab hotkey on local station. Then this combination is transmitted to remote station. Here are steps:
[image]
[image]

To restore the Alt-Tab hotkey on local station click here:
[image]